# How to capture the inner pattern in a recursive matching brackets regex?

Tags: recursion, pcre, brackets

I have line such as these:

```
[something]
[[something else]]
[[[another text here]]]
...
```

And I want to capture the inner text which is `something`, `something else` and `another text here`.

For this I wrote this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/1p7uuo/1):

```
m/^([^\[\]]+|\[(?1)\])$/gm
```

Unfortunately it does not capture the inner text even if I put a capture group around `[^\[\]]+`. I suppose the capture group latch its content at the first match, not during the last recursion.

How is it possible to capture the inner text using a capture group?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Any language compatible with PCRE.

Comment: Anything wrong with `([^\[\]]+)`?

Comment: Yes, the pattern in `[foo]]` matches but there is no matching brackets.

Comment: Yes, there is: `[foo]`. (There's also a `]` after that, but you didn't mention anything about that before. This question is a bit underspecified.)

Comment: Not really because on my question I clearly specified `^` and `$` and I gave one regex that match what I need to match. My only issue is to capture the inner pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to get the capture group content from a recursion at the ground level with PCRE.

A workaround for your particular examples is to not use the recursion feature and to check if there's always a closing bracket for each opening bracket:

```
/\A (?:\[(?=[^]]*(]\1?+)))+ ([^][]*) \1 \z/x
```

(in group 2, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KWyL2s/1))

But you can't use this way with more complicated strings (with several groups at the same level).